# export blender file and import into scenekit does not work

Tags: swift, scenekit, blender

I tried to do this:

1) import file into blender (worked) -> it is the original file from apples vehicle example rc_car

2) exported it to .dae file (seemed to work, but unfortunately not in a way scenekit understands it properly)

(without any changes)

if i then start again the apple vehicle example, the car isn't visible and "invisible" hopping around

i did set global orientation to y_up and apply global orientation checked in blender when exporting.

what am i missing/making wrong?

p.s. what also is weird is that the dae file inside says:

Z_UP

although in export i defined y_up !?

I tried also other formats like obj, ply, alembic ...with the same result or nodes had other names than in the original.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post: 56183036 is how I set the initial orientation and scale on my Turbo Squid models. It looks like you've already figured out that downloaded models don't always start with the rotation desired.

At the end there is a command line for setting Y-Up.  Blender versions have changed since I did this, so I can't speak to y-up within Blender.

Models can be pretty finicky and some I've downloaded, just don't work after export.  I found that trying a very simple model to make sure my math is working first, helps.  A few times, my scale or color scheme was just way off and I didn't know it, couldn't see it, etc.

Hope that helps...

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. i tried it best as i could and as you explained but i couldn't make it work...

Comment: You may just have a bad model.  I've used this technique on all of my models (that's probably over 100), so I know it works under certain conditions.  I load my models like this:  (sorry for the format) func loadCollada(sceneName: String, objName: String) -> SCNNode
    {
        let vScene = SCNScene(named: sceneName)!
        let gObject = vScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: objName, recursively: true)!
        return gObject
    }

Comment: I am using the original car model from Apples Vehicle Demo 

Comment: Any chance you can put your project out on github?  I could try to take a look at at.

Comment: i copied the rc_car.dae from Github: https://github.com/ooper-shlab/SceneKitVehicle1.0-Swift.  If you import rc_car.dae to Blender and export it again and try to use it in XCode - it is useless....the car is then just "bumping around" and invisible. Maybe it is because Apple exported it with their own tool...Anyway, i gave you the bounties for your effort and for "normal" files your example works.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not completely sure what the demo does exactly, but I can see the car, drive it around, bumps into the blocks and moves them.  I can see the car pretty clearly, train is popping smoke.  I'm on an iPhone7.  It does give a lot of errors in the log, but it seems to work right.

Comment: That is the demo, and yes, that is what is does. If you now import this rc_car.dae and Export it again, it won‘t work anymore....

Comment: And this is my „problem“

Comment: I tried exporting the vehicle many different ways and nothing good happened.  Thinking it might have been the blender version, tried exporting and rescaling some of my models with the latest version - worked fine.  Sorry, it just seems to be something about this model and possibly some expertise in blender.

Comment: I think so too. Thank you